# Is there a selection changed event for the listview control?

Tags: c, winapi, listview

Is there an equivalent event to `LBN_SELCHANGE` but for a listview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LVN_ODSTATECHANGED` for the event.

The event parameter is a pointer to a struct of type `NMLVODSTATECHANGED`.  Use the `uNewState` and `uOldState` bit-fields to determine which of these are selection changes (because there are other changes as well).  You're looking for the `LVIS_SELECTED` flag.

Comment: Don't understand, why this answer is upvoted. This message is only available for Owner-Draw List Views.

Answer (score 4):

Use `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notification code.

```
NOTIFY_HANDLER(IDC_FILELIST, LVN_ITEMCHANGED, OnListViewItemChanged)

LRESULT CMainDlg::OnListViewItemChanged(int, LPNMHDR hdr, BOOL&) {
    NMLISTVIEW* lpStateChange = reinterpret_cast<NMLISTVIEW*>(hdr);
    if ((lpStateChange->uNewState ^  lpStateChange->uOldState) & LVIS_SELECTED) {
        // Do something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But don't trust ListView_GetSelectionMark() in this event handler - get selected item with

`ListView_GetNextItem(list_hwnd, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);`